# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle error - FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to install FOSUserBundle on a new symfony2 project. I've followed the steps to get it installed but I'm still having trouble with this error:

```
FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException in FileLoader.php line 97:
Circular reference detected in "/Users/tom/Sites/symfony/todo/app/config/routing_dev.yml" ("/Users/tom/Sites/symfony/todo/app/config/routing_dev.yml" > "/Users/tom/Sites/symfony/todo/app/config/routing.yml" > "/Users/tom/Sites/symfony/todo/app/config/routing_dev.yml").
```

When I try to run `php app/console router:debug` I am getting the error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                              
  Cannot load resource "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml". Make sure the "FOSUserBundle" bu  
  ndle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.
```

Even though I am loading the bundle in the AppKernel.

In routing.yml I have (if it helps):

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Can't seem to find anything on this however I apologise if I haven't searched around well enough.

Comment: why are you using annotation?

Comment: I still get the same error with it. I was just trying different things out to try and fix it.

Comment: Got an error on trying to clear the cache. Basically I've tried to delete the AcmeBundle from the project but forgot to remove the routing prefs in routing_dev. It's working now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I am happy you found solution. Good luck in what is coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had deleted the AcmeDemoBundle from the project but hadn't removed the related routing code from the `routing_dev.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

If cache does not work for you, look if you are include the required namespaces for use annotations routes in your controller, in my case i was missing to add:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
```

in my controller.
I open an issue because the exception throw is wrong for this case, since it says the same error:

```
FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also happen if you delete the line:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

from your Controller. Symfony needs this line for the @Route annotation.

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same problem and error message, but I could not find any circular reference.*

The problem: **indentation** in the yml file.

```
abc_bundle_route:
path:     /my-url/{id}
defaults: { _controller: ABCBundle:Monitor:mycontroller, id: 0 }
    requirements:
        id: -?\d+
```

Is not the same as the (correct):

```
abc_bundle_route:
path:     /my-url/{id}
defaults: { _controller: ABCBundle:Monitor:mycontroller, id: 0 }
requirements:
    id: -?\d+
```

By setting the correct indentation, the error was solved.