# Injecting services into Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning Symfony2 and I am strugling with injecting services into my controller. I get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Inter\DemoBundle\Controller\DataController::__construct() must be an instance of Inter\DemoBundle\Factory\ObjectFactory, none given, called in /home/tomazi/Dev/interface.test/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2138 and defined
```

I created a very basic structure Interface --> Factory --> Controller

My interface:

```
<?php
namespace Inter\DemoBundle\Interfaces;

interface ObjectInterface {

    public function create($testObject);

}
```

My Factory:

```
<?php
namespace Inter\DemoBundle\Factory;
use Inter\DemoBundle\Interfaces\ObjectInterface;

class ObjectFactory implements ObjectInterface{

    public function create($testObject)
    {
        $testObject = 'Hello World';
        return $testObject;
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
<?php
namespace Inter\DemoBundle\Controller;
use Inter\DemoBundle\Factory\ObjectFactory;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DataController
{
    public $object;

    public function __construct(
        ObjectFactory $objectFactory
    ){
        $this->object = $objectFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     * @return ObjectFactory
     */
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->object;
    }

}
```

My Services.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <!--Factory Services-->
        <service id="inter.factory.object_factory"
                 class="Inter\DemoBundle\Factory\ObjectFactory">
        </service>

        <!--Controller Services-->
        <service id="inter.controller" class="Inter\DemoBundle\DataController">
            <argument type="service" id="inter.factory.object_factory" />
        </service>
    </services>

</container>
```

I am new to services judging by the error i am doing something wrong in services.xml but I am unable to find the mistake Can someone see what I am doing wrong..?

Regards

I think the Injection is now working but still get these new errors:

```
FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException in FileLoader.php line 97:
Circular reference detected in 

"/home/tomazi/Dev/interface.test/app/config/routing_dev.yml" 

("/home/tomazi/Dev/interface.test/app/config/routing_dev.yml" > 

"/home/tomazi/Dev/interface.test/app/config/routing.yml" > 

"/home/tomazi/Dev/interface.test/src/Inter/DemoBundle/Controller/" > 

"/home/tomazi/Dev/interface.test/app/config/routing_dev.yml").
```

Comment: Are your routes mapping the controller as a service? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: Yes I did look at the cookbook. but still cannot spot the issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your routing to refer to it as a service. For instance:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
hello:
    path:     /hello
    defaults: { _controller: inter.controller:indexAction }
```

If you are using annotations

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", service="inter.controller")
 */
public function test()
{
    return $this->object;
}
```

Comment: Owww this is actually a very good point but i am using annotations if you look in my DataCOntroller. HOw can I add defaults: { }  there...? by annotations

Comment: same thing for annotations

Comment: `@Route("/test", defaults={ _controller: inter.controller:testAction })`

Comment: I think your answer solved what I was after but now I get more errors i add them to the question if you mind have a look

Comment: @Tomazi, this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344078/symfony2-fosuserbundle-error-fileloaderimportcircularreferenceexception

Comment: generally, I would advise you to create a separate question for each issue

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this extending your controller from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`. It's a base Symfony class that extends `ContainerAware`, so it knows the container.

If you do that, you could simply resolve all your dipendeces like this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $someService = $this->get('some.service');
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Two things:

1. You need to pass a valid ObjectFactory object into your constructor. (your error says it isn't receiving one)
2. You need to add "Action" to your method on your controller(*). Make sure your route is set properly, clear your cache, and try again.

*http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html#referring-to-the-service

Comment: The Q is about service injection. It isn't him calling the constructor so its not up to him to pass anything.